# Spoofing Windows 7/8 Mac address with 00: manufacturer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, mac-address, spoofing

As I am sure everyone knows starting with Windows Vista, you are not able to spoof MAC address to something that starts with a 00:

For a project I am doing I have to spoof it as starting with 00:

I know you can do it on DD-WRT routers and Linux boxes. I was wondering if anyone knows of a hack to be able to do it on Windows 7/8 ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can change it in the registry: http://www.windowsreference.com/networking/how-to-change-mac-address-in-windows-registry/    And if you don't like modifying your registry by hand, there is an autoit app that will do it for you: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/madmacs-mac-spoofer